# WPF: Why does hidden content accept user Action?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a project I've created in order to test UI/UX FX in C#/XML. When the user selects "Get Started", a series of animations occur.

Despite *GridLeft: LeftContent2* & *GridLeft: LeftContent3* having an Opacity of 0.0, they can still be accessed by the user at runtime. In WinForms, I used Visual Studio's Document Outline to create a hierarchy - the panels below the WinForm Panel at the top of the Hierarchy could not be accessed unless the uppermost panel was hidden. I assumed that it would be the same for Grids, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

[image: image hierarchy]

```
<!-- Reduces Left Content Opacity -->
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftContent1" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.375">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>

        <!-- Displays New Left Content2 Opacity -->
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftContent2" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.375">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
        
        <!-- Displays New Left Content3 Opacity -->
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftContent3" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.75">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
```

When the user selects the "Get Started" button, the white grid expands left, resulting in the left grid to go from Opacity="0.0" to Opacity="1.0" (and the opposite for LeftContent2 and 3) at the same time. This results in LeftContent2 and LeftContent3 able to be accessed.

The button is unable to be selected because LeftContent3 is in front of it (with 0 opacity); the user can interact with the contents despite it not being visible. Is there a new way to modify the hierarchy of Window elements?

Comment: Opacity isn't isenabled. You can hit test/ click transparent filled controls. Yiu coukd set isenabled, or you could set visibility to collapsed. Hidden would also work.

Comment: `Opacity` in WPF is basically only an effect. It doesn't change anything in the behavior. Use `IsEnabled` or `IsHitTestVisible` instead.

Comment: @dymanoid ah, interesting. If you write your response as an answer, I'll mark you accordingly :-)